# Creating an Asynchronous Serial queue in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I need to create a queue that executes asynchronously, but the order in which the tasks execute must be serial

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.app", NULL); //create a serial queue can either be null or DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL

dispatch_async(queue,
                ^{

                //Mycode for doing background http

                }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you are doing it correctly,

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.app", NULL); //create a serial queue can either be null or DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL

dispatch_async(queue,
                ^{
task1;
task2;
...

all this tasks wil be done done sequentially 


                }
```

Comment: what happens incase another new queue is created in the same order will be it be sequential?